# How to match the borderRadius of a child view with the parent view borderRadius

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Does anyone know how to fix the borderRadius issue in the following? The borderTopLeftRadius and borderTopRightRadius are set to 30 as is the borderRadius in the parent view, but there's whitespace, and they aren't matching up.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
 <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.cardHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.cardHeaderText}>Title</Text>
        </View>
 </View>
```

Styling:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    card: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        margin: 10,
        width: '95%',
        height: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        borderRadius: 30,
        borderWidth: 5,
      },
      cardHeader: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '12%',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        borderBottomWidth: 5,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
      },
     cardHeaderText: {
       fontSize: 20,
       fontWeight: 'bold',
       paddingHorizontal: 16,
  },
    
    )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of the inner View should be equal to the outer radius minus the width of the border.  So, 30-5=25.

Answer (score 0):

You can use border radius = 25 as Abe mentioned or

you can remove border radius of cardHeader and add overflow:"hidden" to the card

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    card: {
        ...all your styles,
        overflow: "hidden"
      },
      cardHeader: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '12%',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        borderBottomWidth: 5,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        //borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        //borderTopRightRadius: 30,
      },  
    )}
```